# JOIN two tables and get results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, join

I have two tables as below:

```
tbl_main
----------------------------------
id | bucket | amount 
1  |  1     | 10
2  |  2     | 10
3  |  1     | 20
4  |  4     | 10
5  |  5     | 20
6  |  6     | 30
7  |  6+    | 50
8  |  3     | 30
9  |  5     | 50
```

And another table as below

```
tbl_sub
----------------------------------
id | bucket | amount | status
1  |  1     | 10     |  1
2  |  1     | 10     |  1
3  |  1     | 20     |  1
4  |  4     | 10     |  2
5  |  5     | 20     |  1
```

I want join this two tables using buckets and get there total sum of each bucket in two tables wherever table **tbl_sub** column **status** is 1

Expected result is

```
bucket | main_amount | sub_amount
-----------------------------------
 1     |      30     |     40       
 2     |      10     |      0       
 3     |      30     |      0      
 4     |      10     |      0      
 5     |      70     |     20      
 6     |      30     |      0     
 6+    |      50     |      0
```

I am not getting it. Where am I going wrong here's my query

```
SELECT cl.bucket
     , SUM(cl.amount) as main_total
FROM `tbl_main` cl
    JOIN(SELECT bucket, SUM(amount)
         FROM `tbl_sub`
         WHERE status = '1'
         GROUP BY bucket) fl on cl.bucket = fl.bucket
 GROUP BY cl.bucket
```

Here's schema and [Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/odEDBMaedTaE25YYcBudL3/0) link of same

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_main` ( `id` INT ,  `bucket` VARCHAR(5) ,  `amount` INT ,    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`));     

CREATE TABLE `tbl_sub` ( `id` INT  ,  `bucket` VARCHAR(5) ,  `amount` INT ,  `status` INT,    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`));


INSERT INTO `tbl_main` (`id`, `bucket`, `amount`) VALUES ('1', '1', '10'), ('2', '2', '10'), ('3','1', '20'), ('4', '4', '10'), ( '5','5', '20'), ( '6','6', '30'), ( '7','6+', '50'), ('8','3', '30'), ('9', '5', '50');


INSERT INTO `tbl_sub` (`id`, `bucket`, `amount`, `status`) VALUES ( '1','1', '10', '1'), ('2','1', '10', '1'), ('3','1', '20', '1'), ('4','4', '10', '2'), ('5','5', '20', '1');
```

Comment: @Snow so sorry my bad...

Comment: You are summing tbl_sub  but not selecting it?

Comment: Why bucket 1 then main_amount is 20 and not 30?

Comment: @JoeTaras Typing Mistake

Comment: @user10384418: Fix it and check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Use a main query to get the main_amount and use a subquery to compute the sub_amount linked to main bucket, as follow:

```
SELECT cl.bucket,SUM(cl.amount) as main_total,
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(s.amount) FROM `tbl_sub` s WHERE s.status='1' AND s.bucket = 
cl.bucket), 0)
FROM `tbl_main` cl
GROUP BY cl.bucket
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/896f70/4/0)

Comment: thank you it worked. But How it works I am getting confused.

Comment: @user10384418: The main query works on main_:amount, the subquery is linked with bucket field (as a JOIN operation), so I've calculated all sub_amount with the same bucket and the status = 1. Subquery is powerful ;)

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6HeLqakztTGc55RaDssoQ7/1)**

You need 2 separated queries

```
SELECT t.bucket
     , t.main_total
     , COALESCE(p.sub_total, 0) as sub_total
FROM ( SELECT bucket, SUM(amount) as main_total
       FROM `tbl_main`
       GROUP BY bucket) as t
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT bucket, SUM(amount) as sub_total
       FROM `tbl_sub`
       WHERE status='1'
       GROUP BY bucket) as p
 ON t.bucket = p.bucket
ORDER BY t.bucket
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things wrong with your query:

1. you are not using the calculated amount from the sub query
2. you are using a join which will only return matched records - use a left join to get everything from tbl_main and coalesce to set nulls to zero

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t
(id int, bucket int, amount int);
insert into t values
(1  ,  1     , 10),
(2  ,  2     , 10),
(3  ,  1     , 20),
(4  ,  4     , 10),
(5  ,  5     , 20),
(6  ,  6     , 30),
(7  ,  6     , 50),
(8  ,  3     , 30),
(9  ,  5     , 50);
create table t1(id int, bucket int, amount int, status int);
insert into t1 values
(1  ,  1     , 10     ,  1),
(2  ,  1     , 10     ,  1),
(3  ,  1     , 20     ,  1),
(4  ,  4     , 10     ,  2),
(5  ,  5     , 20     ,  1);

SELECT cl.bucket
     , SUM(cl.amount) as main_total
     , coalesce(max(subamt),0) subamt
FROM t cl
left JOIN(SELECT bucket, SUM(amount) subamt
         FROM t1
         WHERE status = '1'
         GROUP BY bucket) fl on cl.bucket = fl.bucket
 GROUP BY cl.bucket;

+--------+------------+--------+
| bucket | main_total | subamt |
+--------+------------+--------+
|      1 |         30 |     40 |
|      2 |         10 |      0 |
|      3 |         30 |      0 |
|      4 |         10 |      0 |
|      5 |         70 |     20 |
|      6 |         80 |      0 |
+--------+------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

this could be written less verbosely using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT t.bucket
     , SUM(t.amount) as main_total
     , sum(case when t1.amount is not null and t1.status = 1 then t1.amount else 0 end )subamt
FROM t 
left join t1 on  t1.bucket = t.bucket
group by t.bucket;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also , use `with as` :

```
with sub_tab as (SELECT bucket, SUM(amount) as sub_total
       FROM `tbl_sub`
       WHERE status='1'
       GROUP BY bucket)

SELECT t.bucket
     , SUM(t.amount) as main_total 
     , COALESCE(sub_tab.sub_total, 0) as sub_total
     from `tbl_main` t join sub_tab on 
 ON t.bucket = sub_tab.bucket
ORDER BY t.bucket
```